# How can I check the value of an aggregated field without direct access to Solr?

Tags: search

I'm using Search API Solr on Pantheon (which means I don't have direct access to the Solr backend), and I've set up an aggregated field in the UI.  This aggregated field is a **Fulltext** aggregation of a boolean field and a Countries module field, but it isn't working as I am expecting.

Search API Views allows the indexed fields to be displayed, but it does not display the values of aggregated fields.  I can filter by the value of the aggregated field, but since I don't know what the values look like in the aggregated field, I'm at a loss about what to input. So I need to check the value of the aggregated field somehow, but there appears to be no way to do this through any of the module UIs.

**What I tried**

I have tried running `dpm()` on the `$view` object through a views template, but as far as I can tell the aggregated fields are not stored there; they are queried on the Solr server, so Views doesn't touch them directly.

As an alternate approach, I went to the search index config page (`/admin/config/search/search_api/server/MYINDEX/edit`) and selected *Retrieve result data from Solr*, but that didn't give me the values of the fields, either.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in Views.

Go to the search index config page (/admin/config/search/search_api/server/MYINDEX/edit) and selected Retrieve result data from Solr.  Then clear all caches a few times to be sure they are really clear.

After that, you can go back to the view and add the aggregated fields as **Fields** to the display.